# how to use compositer nodes on a render farm?

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-passes

When i use sheep it it only uses one of my layers, it will not add shadows or background videos. I have done some research and figured out that sheep it does not support using the compositing nodes. So i'm wondering if i have the render of one of the layers. Can i send another one of the layers through the render farm and then combine them somehow? Maybe? Let me know

Answer (score 1):

At GarageFarm.NET we support compositor nodes in Blender. they should work the same way as on your end. If you have multiple layers to render in the scene, then all of them will render and will ve combined as you set it up in the compositor.

If you wish to save different layers from the compositor for later post-production, then you can use the File Output node to export it. All the File Outputls nodes are correctly saved on our end. You can also use multi-layer EXR for your output which will have all your passes.

I encourage you to test our render farm. We offer trial credits so in this way you can check if everything works as you expected without any costs.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the render farm.

Some will allow you to render your project as you have it on your computers, others don't.

Consult with the particular render farm you are using.